# How to generate pdf from markdown using php?

Tags: php, pdf, markdown

I'm looking for a solution to make a pdf from a markdown file using PHP.
I need to use custom styles as well. So i'm wondering if parsing markdown then going with webkittopdf and using custom css styles will do it.

Have you used anything that can make the job ?
Any clue ?

Thanks

Comment: Is this something you want to do once?  ala 'Print to File' -> pdf?  or is this something you need to automate and perform repeatedly?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at PrinceXML.

It's definitely the best HTML/CSS to PDF converter out there, although it's not free (But hey, your programming is not free either, so if it saves you 10 hours of work, you're home free.)

Also I would recommend you to try this one: http://www.tcpdf.org/
I had a lot of success converting HTML pages with CSS into PDF files.